# Xpath - how to grab contents of div but exclude inner div

Tags: xpath

I want to grab all the text **after** the div that is called: `<p class="meta"></p>` so I basically **do not** want the content contained in this div. Everything else after I do want, so everything after the closing p tag.

Here is the full code:

```
<div id="post">
    <p class="meta"> <img src='http://images.test.com/bin/famfamfam_flags/png/gb.png' border="0" align="absmiddle" alt='Flag of United Kingdom' onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='/bin/famfamfam_silk/gifs/flag_blue.gif'; return false;"/>
        &nbsp;
        <a href="http://www.test-page.html" rel="tag" class="location">New Zealand</a>,
        <a href="http://www.test.com/s/England" title="title text">a link</a>,
        <a href="http://www.test.com/test-page.html" rel="tag">NZ</a>
        <br/>
        <span class="date">Sunday, November 25, 2012</span>
        <br/>
        <iframe class="like_frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none ;overflow:hidden; width:327px; padding-top:14px; height:24px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
    </p>
    Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text  Lorum ipsum text.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `following-sibling`:

```
//p[@class="meta"]/following-sibling::node()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//p[@class="meta"]/following-sibling::node()'
Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum
text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text Lorum ipsum text.
```

Comment: Hi, that is great...but...it removes any words that have an html b tag wrapped around them. Any idea how I avoid this? Example, it removes this word '<b>Vietnam,</b>'

Comment: @RichStevens I've updated the answer (using `node` instead of `text`). Check it out.